# Iterative findMin() in Binary Search Tree implemented with unique_ptr

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree, unique-ptr

I have implemented a BST using the usual unique_ptr:

```
class BinarySearchTree
{
public:
struct Node {
    Node(int k)
    {
        key = k;
        left = nullptr;
        right = nullptr;
    }
    int key;
    // This will auto-destroy all child nodes when this Node is destroyed
    std::unique_ptr<Node> left;
    std::unique_ptr<Node> right;
};

BinarySearchTree():
      m_root(nullptr)
    , m_depth(0)
{}

void deleteKey(int key)
{
    deleteKeyRec(key, m_root);
}

void deleteKeyRec(int key, std::unique_ptr<Node>& node)
{
    if (key == node->key) {
        // This node needs to be deleted and replaced with one of its children
        if (node->left == nullptr && node->right == nullptr) {
            // Node to be deleted has no children
            node = nullptr;
        }
        else if (node->left != nullptr && node->right == nullptr) {
            // Only left child present
            node = std::move(node->left);
        }
        else if (node->left == nullptr && node->right != nullptr) {
            // Only right child present
            node = std::move(node->right);
        }
        else {
            // Both children present, find minimum node in left subtree and replace
            auto minNode = findMin(node->left);
            node->key = minNode->key;
            deleteKeyRec(minNode->key, minNode);                
        }
    }
    else if (key < node->key) {
        deleteKeyRec(key, node->left);
    }
    else if (key > node->key) {
        deleteKeyRec(key, node->right);
    }
}

std::unique_ptr<Node> findMin(std::unique_ptr<Node> & node)
{
    Node *current = node.get();
    while (current->left) {
        current = current->left.get();
    }
    return std::make_unique<Node>(current);
}

private:
    std::unique_ptr<Node> m_root;   // Clean-up all children when this object is destroyed
    int m_depth;

};
```

I am trying to implement findMin() iteratively, and to have it return a unique_ptr& so I can use it in deleteKeyRec() to delete the minimum node. But it seems that I cannot return unique_ptr& from findMin(). Is there another way to implement findMin() iteratively?

The specific error from MSVC is in this line in findMin():
        return std::make_unique(current);

Error   C2664   'BinarySearchTree::Node::Node(BinarySearchTree::Node &&)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'BinarySearchTree::Node *' to 'int'

It seems I should not make a new unique_ptr using the current Node*. But then how do I iterate through the tree?

---

Modified code with the logic for the last case inline:

```
void deleteKeyRec(int key, std::unique_ptr<Node>& node)
{
    if (key == node->key) {
        // This node needs to be deleted and replaced with one of its children
        if (node->left == nullptr && node->right == nullptr) {
            // Node to be deleted has no children
            node = nullptr;
        }
        else if (node->left != nullptr && node->right == nullptr) {
            // Only left child present
            node = std::move(node->left);
        }
        else if (node->left == nullptr && node->right != nullptr) {
            // Only right child present
            node = std::move(node->right);
        }
        else {
            // Both children present, find minimum node in right subtree and replace 'node'
            Node *owner = nullptr;         // stays one step behind current after first iteration
            Node *current = node->right.get();
            while (current->left.get()) {
                owner = current;
                current = current->left.get();
            }

            //auto minNode = findMin(node->left.get());
            node->key = current->key;      // transfer the key here, we do not free the memory of this node.
            if (owner == nullptr) {
                // The right node of 'node' is the correct replacement as it has no children
                node->right = nullptr;  // delete the node from which key was copied
            }
            else {
                // A left node was found when traversing the right subtree of 'node', so that node's owner now will have no left child!
                // This left child thats being deleted has already had its key copied to 'node' via 'current'
                owner->left = nullptr;   // delete the node from which key was copied
            }
        }
    }
    else if (key < node->key) {
        deleteKeyRec(key, node->left);
    }
    else if (key > node->key) {
        deleteKeyRec(key, node->right);
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems passing the std::unique_ptr<Node>& to deleteKeyRec() may not be a good idea after all. I should probably switch to raw pointers for this traversal + delete operation as this function does not take any ownership of any node.

Answer (score 1):

A `find` function should return a reference/pointer/iterator to the found element. It should not return an owning pointer at all. Similarly it should not take an owning pointer as argument. It should take a reference/pointer/iterator to a node instead.

Every object/node must be owned by *exactly one* `std::unique_ptr`. So if you are not intending to *remove* the found node from the tree, then you should not return it as `std::unique_ptr`.

For example:

```
Node& findMin(const Node& node)
{
    Node *current = node.get();
    while (current->left) {
        current = current->left.get();
    }
    return *current;
}
```

---

You have the same problem with `deleteKeyRec`. The argument should not be a `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: Agreed regarding findMin(). However for the std::unique_ptr& used in deleteKeyRec(), I need to adjust the owning unique_ptr in the function to remove the found node. So I need the ptr reference or the tree will not get adjusted. I decided to pull the logic inline for the last case where a node has 2 children, and the minimum key in the right subtree needs to replace the deleted node. Appended code to the original question, which seems to work. I used an extra Node* to keep track of the owning node one step behind and handled a special case. Works till something better is suggested.